# Search specific column of CSV file for first n occurrences containing a string with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, csv, parsing

I'm trying to search through the first column of a large CSV file (about 200k rows) with node.js for the first 5 occurrences containing a specific string. Many solutions I've seen read the entire file or the whole row each time and I would like to avoid this for performance, as each column contains 50+ rows. I'm open to solutions with or without the use of modules (such as csv or fast-csv), with speed as the priority over ease of programming

Cheers

Comment: In order to extract only a certain column, any module will need to iterate over each row anyway in order to split them at the separator. So I doubt you will find a solution that performs better.

Comment: When you think of it very low level, you can't skip parts of the file because you need to get every comma (until you arrived at the desired column) but also every linebreak. So even on a low level I see no chance of reading only certain columns. CSV files after all are just text files.

Comment: Ya I guess whatever processes the CSV file needs to hit a newline character in order to proceed to the next row,  thus having to read the whole row every time. Are there any options that read row by row and not scan through the whole file first?

Comment: Can you post a sample csv? Couple lines?